# Skip every other cell on hover with highlight in CSS

Tags: php, jquery, css, html-table, hover

I have the following code that displays an html table of words and their counts from a PHP associative array. A table can have up to 10 columns by 10 rows (it's variable):

```
| col1  | col2 | col3  | col4 |
|-------|------|-------|------|
| word1 |  50  | word4 |  25  |
| word2 |  44  | word5 |  21  |
| word3 |  39  | word6 |  16  |, etc.
```

The CSS highlights and underscores individual `<td>` cells on hover. However, I need the hover/highlight/underscore to work ONLY on the `<td>` cells with words--not on the numbers. The words will always be in odd-numbered columns--and numbers will always be in even-numbered columns.

Can you please suggest the code that will do that? I've read that I might need to do this in jQuery because of browser issues related to hover. Here's what I have so far. Thank you in advance. :)

```
?>
<table id="word-table">
<?echo "<th>Word Counts</th>";?>
  <tbody>
    <?
      foreach ($rows as $cols) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td class="nth-child(2n-1)">', $cols) . '</td></tr>';
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?

#word-table td:nth-child(2n-1) {
    background: #CCFFCC;
}

#word-table td:nth-child(2n) {
    display: block;
    background: #CCE0FF;
    margin-right: 7px;
    text-align: center;
}

#word-table tbody td:hover 
{
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: #FFFFCC;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this, you can just use CSS.

```
td:nth-child(odd):hover{
  ...
}
```

Works reliably in most browsers: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PV6jV/

Also, I notice you're adding `nth-child(2n-1)` as a class - `:nth-child` is a pseudo class, so you don't have to actually add it.

Comment: `nth-child` is not support for IE8 or less, and in most of the case, I would assume OP requires it to work for < IE8

Comment: @Neverever - I put the link to caniuse.com - they can decide whether or not this answer is useful and suits their purposes. I don't support IE8 in my work, and neither does Google (in terms of their apps).

Comment: use `nth-of-type` http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

Comment: @c4p - While that would be better in other circumstances, you shouldn't have any other children elements inside a `<tr>` (other than `<td>`), so `:nth-child` would be fine here.

Comment: @ahren, that worked in two seconds and yes, you're right, it even worked without the 'nth-child(2n-1)' just fine. Thanks for the fiddle, and link to 'caniuse', and the extra discussion was helpful, too. :)

Comment: @Andreas3204 - No worries. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit is better

```
<? foreach ($rows as $cols): ?>
  <tr>
       <td> <?php echo $cols[0]; ?></td>
       <td class="highlight"> <?php echo $cols[1]; ?></td>
       <td> <?php echo $cols[0]; ?></td>
       <td class="highlight"> <?php echo $cols[3]; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: David, thank you for your time and consideration. I like your idea about being explicity. But I'm pretty new at this and just went for the two-second css fix posted above. Since the number of table rows and columns are variable, I wasn't sure how to implement your solution for any combination of 1-to-10 rows and/or columns (e.g., I could have 8 columns and 9 rows... Is there an easy way to do this with a while loop and counter(s)? Thanks again, David.

Comment: foreach() can also be used as foreach($cols as $column_index, $column), put in tandem with % Modulus.  You can get all even columns by doing $column_index % 2.  From there its just a simple if() {} else {}.

Comment: @Andreas3204 If your new to programming, I recommend checking out Codeigniter, it's a slightly older PHP framework that has some really good documentation and because it is an MVC ( model view controller ) system it will make you a lot more attractive as a candidate for hire.

Comment: Thank you, kindly, @David. I'm going to tinker with with looping structure you suggested. I agree with you: I should be thinking in terms of an MVC framework and like what I see already on Codeignitor. I'm quite sure you guessed that I was "avoiding" this additional layer of complexity. :) Thanks again for your help.